# saving facebook mutual friends to array or dictionary

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

This is probably a very novice question and I'm embarrassed to ask, but I've wasted a bunch of time trying to figure this out.

I followed facebook's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user.context/mutual_friends) and can now successfully retrieve mututal friends. The problem, I'm having trouble saving them to an array or dictionary. My goal is to save the values so that I can provide a mutual friends feed.

This is the result from facebook

```
2015-02-08 14:23:41.747 Madada[1989:500881] RESULT OF FB {
     context =     {
       "mutual_friends" =         {
         data =             (
                            {
                id = 341355692798276;
                name = "name";
            },
                            {
                id = 1600005380218938;
                name = "name";
            }
        );
        paging =             {
            cursors =                 {
                after = "MTYwMDAwNTM4MDIxODkzNA==";
                before = MzQxMzU1NjkyNzM4Njgz;
            };
        };
        summary =             {
            "total_count" = 3;
        };
    };
};
id = 1380880992219300;
```

}

This is my ios code

```
NSNumber *total = result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"summary"][@"total_count"];
                                  NSLog(@"TOTAL FRIENDS %@", total);
                                  for(int i=0;i<[result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"data"] count];i++)
                                  {
                                      [self.mutualFriends addObject:result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"data"]];
                                      NSLog(@"MUTUAL FRIENDS ARRAY : %@", self.mutualFriends);
                                  }
```

I tried messing around with this, but the result of the array is NULL for each user retrieved. When I added [@"id"] at the end, it gives me this message.

> unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x178c60c0

I'm almost certain that this is just a basic syntax issue, and as I said before, I'm embarrassed to have to ask, but thanks in advance to the awesome community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have two issues. First array being NULL. I would make sure you are initalizing your NSMutableArray before you start adding objects to it.

```
self.mutualFriends = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

Second issue is that you can't get the id directly because you are iterating through an array and need to get a dictionary from the array first. See friendData in the sample.

```
NSNumber *total = result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"summary"][@"total_count"];
NSLog(@"TOTAL FRIENDS %@", total);

for(int i=0;i<[result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"data"] count];i++)
{
    NSDictionary *friendData = result[@"context"][@"mutual_friends"][@"data"][i];

    [self.mutualFriends addObject:friendData[@"id"]];
    NSLog(@"MUTUAL FRIENDS ARRAY : %@", self.mutualFriends);
}
```

Also it is super easy to get lost doing `result[@"thisThing][@"otherThing][@"evenMoreStuff]`. Just some advice I would avoid doing that and create a local NSDictionary or NSArray as you move through result.

Hopefully that helps and solves your problem.